# Compile gawk executable for another server

Tags: linux, compilation, static-libraries, libraries, autotools

I have a server where I cannot directly compile the version of gawk which I need for certain processing.  So I am trying to find out how I can compile it on another platform and transfer the executable to the server and execute it there.  I tried copying the existing gawk from my laptop's distribution (Linux Mint) to the server (Redhat), but it does not have the necessary libraries, at least not where the executable is looking for them.

```
$ ./gawk --version
./gawk: error while loading shared libraries: libsigsegv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there a standard way to compile a program like gawk such that it does not rely on external libraries (almost like an AppImage I suppose)?  Since gawk uses make for the installation, I'm hoping there are some options I can set there.

Comment: *"Is there a standard way to compile a program like gawk such that it does not rely on external libraries"* - No. But you should probably `./configure --help`, and then use as many `--without-XXX` as practical. Maybe better, setup a VM like the target server. Then your local build will link to libraries available on the server. Since it is a Red Hat server the closest is probably CentOS (and certainly not Debian, Ubuntu or Mint).

Comment: Thanks jww.  I set up a CentOS VM and attempted to build gawk with GMP and MFPR libraries (which are required for the bignum support), but can't get the compilation to include those.

Comment: You'd need to build gawk using static libraries, meaning something like `make LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bstatic` instead of just `make`. The linker option `-Bstatic` will be passed by the compiler to the linker `ld` to say "I prefer that you link static libs". This will link the static versions of libgmp.a and libmpfr.a to the gawk binary, if installed. If they're not installed, you'd need to compile those packages separately and use `./configure --with-gmp=/path/to/gmp-and-mpfr --with-mpfr=/path/to/gmp-and-mpfr` if possible, else `env LDFLAGS='-Wl,-L/path/to/gmp-and-mpfr-prefix/lib' ./configure`.

Comment: When I need a more recent version of a program than is packaged with CentOS / RHEL, I normally look for a recent enough source package in [Fedora's Koji repository](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packages), and build that.  Sometimes this requires retrieving dependencies and building those, too.  I suggest choosing the latest successfully-built one from the oldest Fedora that supports any acceptable ones.  Having successfully built an RPM (or several), you should be able to install it on the target machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much for the help provided in the comments to my original post.  Below is a summary of how it worked in the end.  I saw that `make` resulted in the following as the final compilation command for creating the gawk executable:

```
gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -DNDEBUG  -L/usr/lib64//lib -o gawk array.o awkgram.o builtin.o cint_array.o command.o debug.o eval.o ext.o field.o floatcomp.o gawkapi.o gawkmisc.o int_array.o io.o main.o mpfr.o msg.o node.o profile.o re.o replace.o str_array.o symbol.o version.o support/libsupport.a -lmpfr -lgmp -ldl -lm
```

So I modified that gcc command as below:

Download and compile the mpfr libraries (just `./configure` and `make`).
Download and compile the gmp libraries (just `./configure` and `make`).
Download and compile gawk-4.2.1.

```
./configure
make
gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -DNDEBUG  -L/usr/lib64//lib -o gawk array.o awkgram.o builtin.o cint_array.o command.o debug.o eval.o ext.o field.o floatcomp.o gawkapi.o gawkmisc.o int_array.o io.o main.o mpfr.o msg.o node.o profile.o re.o replace.o str_array.o symbol.o version.o support/libsupport.a  -Bstatic -L /home/osboxes/Downloads/mpfr-4.0.1/src/.libs/ -l:libmpfr.a -L /home/osboxes/Downloads/gmp-6.1.2/.libs/ -l:libgmp.a -Bdynamic -ldl -lm
```

That resulted in a gawk executable that had mpfr and gmp libraries statically linked, so when I transferred it to the server which did not have libmpfr.so already installed, it was able to execute with the static library.

**Before adding the static libraries:**

```
[osboxes@osboxes Gawk]$ ldd gawk
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe17750000)
    libmpfr.so.4 => /lib64/libmpfr.so.4 (0x00007fca2042d000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /lib64/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fca201b5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fca1ffb1000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fca1fcaf000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fca1f8e2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fca20688000)
```

**After adding the static libraries:**

```
[osboxes@osboxes gawk-4.2.1]$ ldd gawk
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1b8d5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f69363b0000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f69360ae000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6935ce1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f69365b4000)
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a standard way to compile a program like gawk such that it does not rely on external libraries (almost like an AppImage I suppose)?

Why not make an AppImage indeed?

Comment: I can't make an AppImage is because it needs to be executed on a server that does not have AppImage installed.

Comment: There is no AppImage runtime that would have to be installed.